# How to Separate NSString Data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsscanner

I Have one NSString* string;

String = "ID: 12 34 56 78       Class:C"

Now i want to distinguish the ID data in one variable and Class data in another,
How can i separate this two from single String

I have used :

```
NSScanner* Scanner = [NSSCanner ScannerWithString:@"String"]
 NSCharacterSet* seperator = [NSCharacterSet CharacterSetWithCharacterInString:@":"];  
 NSString* text; 

 while([Scanner isAtEnd] == NO)
 {
    [Scanner ScanUpToCharacterFromSet:Seperator intoString:@"text"];
    [Scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:newLine intoString:NULL];             
    NSLog(@"%@",text);

 }
```

This won't separate my String from ID and Class, tell me how can i do this 
my O/p should be :

12 34 56 78

C

This is one scenario i have array of Strings and in each i want to separate my string with another keyword ....

Comment: can you tell me exact requirement or what kind of data you have ?

Comment: Hello Samkit Jain,
I have one NSArray named LayoutString containg 13 object
 i tried this 
for(NSString* string in LayoutString)

Comment: Hello Samkit Jain,
I have one NSArray named LayoutString containg 13 object
 i tried this 
for(NSString* string in LayoutString)
{
// when i traverse the array in a loop i get
// "ID:12 34 56 78 class:C" first traverse
// "SEX:M  EYES:BRN HGT:5-09' " and so on
so now i want to display ID:12 34 56 78 in one field
Class:C in different field
SEX:m in another  EYES:BRN in another textField and so on
}

Answer (score 2):

Use NSString's rangeOfString function

```
NSString *myString = @"ID: 12 34 56 78 Class:C";
NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:@"Class"];
NSString *idStr = [myString substringToIndex:range.location];
NSString *classStr = [myString substringFromIndex:range.location];
NSLog(idStr);
NSLog(classStr);
```

I got this on my Log

```
2014-02-07 15:56:29.951 Hello[5493:903] ID: 12 34 56 78 
2014-02-07 15:56:29.959 Hello[5493:903] Class:C
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for you reply
but when i debug this there will be signal abrt
at NSString *classStr = [myString substringFromIndex:range.location];

Comment: I edited the answer (added first line)... the code is exactly what I ran on a little test app, and the output is what I believe you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are the way to go.

First create your NSRegularExpression:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"ID:(.*?)Class:(.*?)" options:0 error:&error];
```

With this you are creating a regular expression to match what's in parentheses. Then, match your regular expresion with your string:

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

NSArray *matchArray = [regex matchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length])];
for(NSTextCheckingResult *result in matchArray)
{
    if(result.range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSInteger rlen = result.numberOfRanges;
        for(NSInteger i=1;i<rlen;i++)
        {
            NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:i];
            [resultArray addObject:[yourString substringWithRange:range]];
        }
    }
}
```

And after this you'll have this:

resultArray[0] => ID data,
resultArray[1] => Class data

You may need to adjust the regular expression to skip blanks, but that's basically it.